# jquery how to know if thead is scroll to top

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

i am using jquery ui layout. In the center pane (ui-layout-content) i have a large table. I made the thead sticky. But i like to change the background-color if the thead is sticked at the top.

This is my html code:

```
<body>
<div class="ui-layout-north">
</div>
<div class="ui-layout-content">
<div>Larum Lipsum .... </div>

<div>
<table class="mytable">
<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Line 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 3</td></tr>
...
<tr><td>Line 10000</td></tr>
</tbody>
</div>
</div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
                    var scroll_start = 0;
                    var startchange = $('.mytable');
                    var offset = startchange.offset();
                    alert('onload:'+offset.top);
                    if (startchange.length) {
                        $(document).scroll(function () {
                            scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
                            alert('scrollstart:'+scroll_start);
                            if (scroll_start > offset.top) {
                                $('.mytable > thead > tr > th').css('background-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,.75)');
                            } else {
                                $('.mytable > thead > tr > th').css('background-color', 'transparent');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

I try to get the position of the table at page load. This works great. And if the user scrolls i check if it is on top or not. But the scroll event is never fired.

If i load the page i see "onload: 209" at the alert box. If i scroll down there is no alert box displayed.

Thanks

Comment: [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Explain: for what reason you need that info?

Comment: Sorry for my worse english, i tried to explain much better.

Comment: Where do you close `</table>` exactly? Can you please fix those markup issues and create a [mcve]? Where is the minimal CSS?

Comment: Why do you use `$(doument).on("scroll"` if you actually your `.mytable` is scrollable? ...or is it?